# Update graph based on time intervals

Tags: neo4j

I've recently started using neo4j and read the corresponding discussions about how to handle time based data, although I will admit that I need to study it in more depth. My problem is that I want to build a graph by taking snapshots at a fixed time interval, and then build the corresponding graph based on those time intervals. So , for example in time t3 I want to be able to see the "active" nodes with edges at this point in time, however I want to keep all the information about the inactive nodes and the relationships that occurred in the past.

Is there a proposed approach for achieving this, since I am not interested in handling time information with too much detail (not interested in hours,minutes,etc), only interested for a fixed interval.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple solution can be to use timestamps on the edges as described on [Ian Robinson's blog post about Time-based versioned Graphs](http://www.neo4j.org/graphgist?608bf0701e3306a23e77) in the Neo4J site.

On top of that where I work we published [a blog post on how to visualize the new time-based structure](http://keylines.com/network-visualization/visualize-neo4j-time-graph), which shows a slightly different representation than the one in the Neo4J browser, with a timebar navigation component as well.

While the blog post is for our product I think it can stil gives the general idea on how to handle such complex visualization.

Comment: @Michael, if you have any additional information or resources I would like to see them. Thanks